# RDLC with user defined types

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

When i am creating new RDLC report, my stored procedure is having user defined types and i am unable to use this procedure in my report. It is throwing an error that we cannot use user defined procedures in a report.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: User-defines types(UDTs) are not supported in the DataSet Designer...